# CUPS uses the wrong DISPLAY parameter

Tags: linux, printing, cups, gnome-3

We are using the Xerox Linux drivers to print on our multifunction printer. Basically, when you print the driver opens a pop-up window to let you choose different printing options, then calls lp for printing.

This works pretty well on single user computer, but when many users are logged-in at the same time on the machine, the driver doesn't know which DISPLAY to use (`:0`, `:1`, `:2`, etc.). Thus when printing, the pop-up appears on `:0` even though a user can be on `:1` or `:2`.

When it comes to printing, the printing subsystem runs as an OS user (`lp` on Debian).  This OS user doesn't have an X session and thus no DISPLAY value.  Since DISPLAY isn't set, the driver assumes `:0` being the typical single-user client display.  Therefore when using the User Switching mechanism, CUPS does not forward the requesting user's DISPLAY so the driver assumes the `:0` display if not specified.  This causes user2's driver interface to be sent to user1's display.

Here is a snippet of the log when printing. You can see I called the process with `tech`, but `lp` is the one printing:

> localhost - tech [06/May/2016:15:06:42 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200
>   362 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
>
> localhost - lp [06/May/2016:15:06:55 -0400] "POST /printers/*xeroxtq1*
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 346 Create-Job successful-ok
>
> localhost - lp [06/May/2016:15:06:55 -0400] "POST /printer /*xeroxtq1*
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 33861 Send-Document successful-ok

I am not looking for a full walkthrough solution here (if you have one I won't spit on it though), but for some hints on what I should try to do. I've thought of:

1 - [Disabling user switching in GNOME3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153930/how-to-permanently-disable-user-switching-in-gnome-3), but this is a last resort solution since it is quite useful for users

2 - Forcing CUPS to call `lp` with the -o DISPLAY option, grepped from the user that called the process. If this were feasible, it would be quite nice.

3 - Force GNOME3 to show currently used user on :0 and move idle ones to other displays.

I have no idea how #2 could be done and I'm not sure if #3 is feasible.

I've already tweaked GNOME3 to log off users that are idle more than 30min, but it's not enough to solve the problem.

Any help?

Comment: File a support request with Xerox for their printer driver to not be crazy?

Comment: Heh, this was their response:

"Development recommends the customer speak to the CUPS support team and see if there is a similar command that can be incorporated into CUPS for this is a way to incorporate the command already provided."

Comment: It also seems #3 is not a solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281606/xorg-switch-display-between-two-users/

Comment: Normally you find a PPD file and hook it up with CUPS so that the only print dialog you see is the OS-provided one.  Did you look into that?  What's the printer model?

Comment: We used to do this, but to have access to the more advanced options (stapling, hole punching, folding in 3 or 4) you need to go with the binary blobs they provide that opens a cute pop-up menu. These are quite huge printers (Xerox ColorQube 9302)